# When I set `HH:mm:ss` on DateFormat, I get `22:42:31 AM` in rare case. ` AM` is unexpected. How can I fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, date-format

I released an global application.
I found a strange formatted timestamp in the log.
It is rare cases less than 1% and I can't find the condition.
Do you know how I fix it?

- Expected: most of log

  ```
  2018-05-24T06:10:20.22220430Z
  ```
- Unexpected: rare cases

  ```
  2018-05-24T06:10:20 AM.22220430Z
  ```
- code

  ```
  public class sample {
      private let formatter = DateFormatter()

      private init() {
          self.formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
          self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.AAAAAAAZZZZZ"
      }
      public func timestamp() -> String {
          return self.formatter.string(from: Date())
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm wondering if you should use `en_US_POSIX` to avoid that case. Could be a local issue. Maybe if you find from where they are (locate the issue in a geographical way).

Comment: try hh:mm:ss instead of HH:mm:ss... I think this issue will replicate on 00:00:00 or 24:00:00

Comment: try this `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` date format

Comment: @Larme, Thank you. I heard that it is necessary to set `en_US_POSIX`. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: @Manish Mahajan, I apologize that my question was not clear and I misled you. I fixed the question.

Comment: @Shahrukh, Thank you, but I expect `.22220430Z` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` represents "Milliseconds in day". It is not the same thing as the fractional seconds that you want. For that, use `S`.

`ZZZZZ` gives a timezone in the format such as `-08:00`. Since you want the actual `Z` to appear in the output to represent Zulu time, Use `X`. `X` combined with the timezone set to 0 seconds from GMT results in `Z` in the output.

The above is based on the assumption that the `.22220430` in your desired output is all the fractional seconds.

Your final format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSX`.

And you must also set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`. You should always use that locale when using `dateFormat` to ensure user preferences don't result in unexpected results.

Also note that you are not really going to get 8 significant digits of fractional seconds. Anything beyond three `S` is probably pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!